# Another Swift compiler error?

Tags: syntax, swift

The following line seems to always have a syntax error, any idea on how to fix it?

```
sourceModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles(nil, forStoreMetadata:metaData)
```

Error is "`Extra argument forStoreMetadata in call`"

The if I try the following

sourceModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles( forStoreMetadata:metaData)

I get a `"Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"`

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bundles` in `mergedModelFromBundles` definition is not optional.So you cannot pass nil instead you need to pass `array` containing `bundles`

```
//bundles is not optional
class func mergedModelFromBundles(bundles: [AnyObject], forStoreMetadata metadata: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> NSManagedObjectModel?
```

try instead

```
     sourceModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles([NSBundle.mainBundle()], forStoreMetadata: metaData)
```